# How to render strings including Ascii characters in Swift

Tags: string, swift, ascii

I have an RSS feed and in its description element (here: www.marketoloji.com/?feed=rss2) I have ascii characters for the ones like `'` or `&` and they are seen as `&#8217;` / `&#38;`. How can I render that description string in Swift so that I wont see ascii characters?

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but pretty much every character you see on this screen (with the exception of that single quote) is ASCII.

Comment: @HotLicks: as you see, i am beginner when it comes to naming the character types :) but i hope you got my point, i simply want to show `'` and `&' instead of `&#8217;` and `&#38;` in my app when i render this text. should i check every character manually or is there an easy way to make this happen in swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSAttributedString to easily convert html code for you using the NSHTMLTextDocumentType option:

```
extension String {
    var htmlString:String {
        return NSAttributedString(data: dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!.string
    }
}


let htmlCode = "&#8217; / &#38;"

htmlCode.htmlString  // "’ / &"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code gives "Declaration is only valid at file scope" error :(

Comment: Just put ir at the bottom of your file or add another file (swift source file) and put it there.